# Yii2: standalone action does not work in event handler

Tags: php, yii, yii2, yii-actions

I'm a beginner in Yii, so don't know, how to solve my problem in most correct way.

There are 2 controllers - `SiteController` and `UsersController`. I need to retrieve some data from DB and output it in layout. In particular, if user1 and user2 added user3 as friend, user3 will see it on main menu panel:
[image]
User have to see it regardless of controller, action of which is running (in pic above user sees `/site/profile` page, but a lot of other pages (in particular `invitations`) render by `users` controller).

I wrote the same actions in 2 controllers:

```
public function getStats () { //it duplicates in UsersController and SiteController
    $recieved_invitations = Invitations::find()->where(['recipient_id'=>\Yii::$app->user->id])->all();
    ...       
    return [$recieved_invitations_count, $received_docs_count];  
}
```

I decided, that, if count need to be in every page, I need trigger it regardless of controllers. So, I wrote in *wep.php*:

```
'on beforeAction' => function ($event) {
    \Yii::$app->session->set('stats', $event->sender->controller->getStats());
}
```

And then in menu in layout I retrieve session vars.

Everything works fine. But `getStats()` action duplicates in controllers. I want **to do it standalone**.

```
//action code (in '@app/components' folder) (just from documentation):
namespace app\components;
use yii\base\Action;
class HelloWorldAction extends Action {
    public function run() {
        return "Hello World";
    }
}

//in 'actions()' in controllers:
parent::actions();
    return [
        'hv' => [
            'class' => 'app\components\HelloWorldAction',
        ]
    ];

//in 'web.php':
'on beforeAction' => function ($event) {
    \Yii::$app->session->set('stats', $event->sender->controller->hv());
}
```

But exception throws: `Calling unknown method: app\controllers\UsersController::hv()`. Also: if I disable `urlManager` in config. file and comment out `beforeAction` handler, action is accessible via this URL:

`http://localhost:8001/index.php?r=users%2Fhv`

Why standalone action fails, if it triggers on `beforeAction` event? And, if it's normal behaviour, what can I do to avoid duplicating `getStats()` method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would actually try to move the getStats method to your User model, that way you can just access it from anywhere in your application by calling it like this:

```
Yii::$app->user->identity->stats;
// OR
Yii::$app->user->identity->getStats();
```

It's usually better to have fat models, simple controllers and views.

Comment: Thanks, it works. But is it correct to put this code into logic, that is responsible for identity? I just don't know much about identity interface in Yii yet, so don't understand, whether this code is available semantically in `User` model...

Comment: [Here](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-structure-models.html#best-practices) are some guidelines of best practices with models, really useful.

Comment: Just to explain a little about how this works: `Yii::$app->user` is an instance of [this class](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-web-user.html), which uses the `getIdentity()` method to access the class you set on `config/web.php`

Comment: Thanks, I read [best practices](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-structure-models.html#best-practices) before, I just meant, that my `getStats()` is logic, that differs from main `User` logic. Ok, I'll resolve it, when my Yii2-experience will become wider. And now - accept your answer, thanks again)